# Create HTML forms dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a big project which contains more then 80 forms. Each transaction having one form, now I think about creating this forms dynamically using Angular. This dynamic form creation process will generate input field with their model name and validation rules. The definition of form I will write in Angular controller. So my curiosity is to know this thinking is practically good or I should think about some other ways. I'm using Node.js with Express js at server side.

Comment: Why don't you use HTML _fragments_, one for each custom form?  You can include these programatically from a controller, or in the actual HTML source code.  This sounds like a much more maintainable approach than having the HTML for these 80+ forms buried in Javascript code somewhere.

Comment: I will just create a json object in controller which will contain field type (text, radio button, check box etc.) ,  Field's model name and field validation now I will use ng-repeat to generate this fields. Is this approach good or some improvement is required?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net as backend, then you can depend on visual studio scaffolding and T4 templates to generate the HTML and JavaScript for your Angular Controllers and Views.

Otherwise, you can have a Json file that has the list of fields for each form and create a directive that accepts the name of the form and read its fields from the json file, then iterate over the list of fields in the form and draw HTML input accordingly, you can include the validation, labels and data type with each field.

You can later save this file in the database and allow the user to edit the file, maybe you can add a view to each form, something like SharePoint when it has a list and then more than one view for each list.

Comment: I am using node js at server side.

Comment: Then use the second solution, store the metadata for the form and read it in a directive to draw the form